# How to change textarea font size without affecting the width

Tags: html, css, textarea

How do I change the font size of the textarea without affecting the width of the textarea box?

I know by applying css such as:

```
textarea {
    font-size:16px;
}
```

However it affects the textarea size.

Comment: fix size of your textarea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code in your width and height in the css.

```
textarea {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

You can also do this in the html by using the rows, and cols attributes:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Comment: @J.Koh Yup! Glad I could help.